# How can I catch when a switch is Toggled in a XAML template I created?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test" 
              x:Class="Test.Templates.SwitchTemplate" 
              x:Name="this" >
    <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

My CS back end looks like this:

```
public partial class SwitchTemplate : StackLayout
{
    public SwitchTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
       
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(IsToggled),
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(SwitchTemplate),
                default(bool));
        
    public bool IsToggled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to have a method called in the back-end CS of the XAML where the template is used when the toggled state changes.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I could code the XAML template, its back end CS and the CS of the XAML where the template is used so that I can do some actions when the toggle state changes?

Comment: There is already an out-of-the-box `Toggled()` event-handler for the Switch control. Here is the sample code on the official site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.switch?view=xamarin-forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this (propertyChanged) to your Create

```
public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(IsToggled),
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(SwitchTemplate),
                default(bool),
                propertyChanged: PropertyChanged);
```

and add this method:

```
private static void PropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (SwitchTemplate)bindable;
    //Do something :)
}
```